# How to extract application/x-gzip response body

Tags: http, gzip, content-type, fiddler, mime

I'm struggling with extracting `application/x-gzip` HTTP responses manually because Fiddler can't extract them. For example, my Android device queries `https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/selfUpdate` from time to time. The response has `Content-Type: application/x-gzip` and the body is only 9 bytes long (hex):

```
0A 03 BA 02 00 2A 02 08 00
```

According to the following W3C paper: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.5
*applications SHOULD consider "x-gzip" and "x-compress" to be equivalent to "gzip" and "compress" respectively.*

However, GZIP should start with hex bytes 1F 8B. And according to [GZIP file format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952#page-5), the header is always 10 bytes long so if the response body has only 9 bytes, it can't be stored as a valid GZIP file. If I store it in a file anyway, none of the following extractors can process it: gzip, arclite, 7-Zip, WinRar. As mentioned before, Fiddler can't extract it too.

Perhaps the GZIP 10-byte header was stripped - let's add it. The file contents is now:

```
1F 8B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0A 03 BA 02 00 2A 02 08 00
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't really change anything, none of the extractors mentioned above can process it.

EDIT:

Looking at a few other `x-gzip` responses from Google servers, the body always starts with 0x0A byte. No other similarity found.

Comment: Nitpick: 2616 3.5 defines Content-**encoding** values; Content-**type** (aka mediatype) `application/gzip` is in 6713. But 6713 bases on 1952 the same way, and the only reasonable expectation is that x-gzip also does, so your actual problem is unchanged.

Comment: That is not any kind of gzip, zlib, or raw deflate data.   Either you are not fetching it properly, or the server is lying to you.